# How to get post using a specific category

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm just getting back into Wordpress and php after a few years away. I'm pretty ignorant when it comes to php syntax so making lots of mistakes.

I need to display a single post on a page, it's title and contents, and it needs to be specific to a category that I've created.

I grabbed this of the web and tried to change it, but I can't get it to work.

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=qaadrant&showposts=1');
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
      // do whatever you want
    ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_content(); ?>"><?php the_content(); ?></a></p>
```

Any help much appreciate. Niall

Comment: Don't use query_posts, [it's bad](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/62744). Use get_posts instead. Try `get_posts(array('category_name' => 'qaadrant', 'numberposts' => 1));` and see if it helps.

Comment: When you say "category that I've created" is it part of the default Posts section categories, or is it a custom post type with custom taxanomy?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Tom, yes the former. I think custom taxonomy is way beyond me at this point.

Comment: Vard, thanks but I can't figure out how that fits in with php syntax (of which I'm pretty ignorant). Do I keep the 'get title' and 'get content' parts? Every combination I've tried just leads to an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use awesome WP_QUERY Class see the reference here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
Using following code to get posts from category you selected. No-paging is set to make query faster:

```
    <?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'category_name' => 'qaadrant',
    'no-paging' => true,    
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <h3><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
        <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>


    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: The word 'codex' makes me want to run for the door :-) I've spent many hours lost and confused in that place. 

I just tried using your code, for which I'm extremely grateful' but when I try it out my page (or sidebar, to be precise) disappears. However, I seem to have got the old code working now.

Comment: @nialldcrowley regarding codex here is my tip that is always move to "Usage" section and see code examples given there, you will find it easy to follow.

Comment: Thank you so much. Really appreciated your help and time.

Comment: You are welcome @nialldcrowley Thanks for accepting my answer! :)